# illegalthreadstateexception thread already started occurs when using thread.start in a FOR loop in Java on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, for-loop

I am using a FOR loop which has been designed to start the thread again on every iteration. The thread is used to extract data from text files.

The error occurs on the second iteration where the error is "illegalthreadstateexception thread already started". I have tried using GetTopics.stop even though it has been deprecated but has not fixed the error. I also use GetTopics.join as a way of making sure the codes do not run simultaneously.

```
private void addTabs(ActionBar actionBar)
{
    ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("All");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);


    for (addTabPosition = 2; addTabPosition < 11; addTabPosition++) {
        Thread GetTopics = new Thread();
        GetTopics.start();

        try {
            GetTopics.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(addTabMessage.contentEquals("FileNotFound")){
            Log.e("skiper", "file skiped" + addTabPosition);

    }else{

        switch (addTabPosition) {
        case 2:
            ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
            tab2.setText(addTabTitle);
            tab2.setTabListener(this);
            actionBar.addTab(tab2);
            break;
        case 3:
            ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionBar.newTab();
            tab3.setText(addTabTitle);
            tab3.setTabListener(this);
            actionBar.addTab(tab3);
            break;
        case 4:
            ActionBar.Tab tab4=actionBar.newTab();
            tab4.setText(addTabTitle);
            tab4.setTabListener(this);
            actionBar.addTab(tab4);
            break;
        case 5:
            ActionBar.Tab tab5=actionBar.newTab();
            tab5.setText(addTabTitle);
            tab5.setTabListener(this);
            actionBar.addTab(tab5);
            break;
        case 6:
            ActionBar.Tab tab6=actionBar.newTab();
            tab6.setText(addTabTitle);
            tab6.setTabListener(this);
            actionBar.addTab(tab6);
            break;
        case 7:
            ActionBar.Tab tab7=actionBar.newTab();
            tab7.setText(addTabTitle);
            tab7.setTabListener(this);
            actionBar.addTab(tab7);
            break;
        case 8:
            ActionBar.Tab tab8=actionBar.newTab();
            tab8.setText(addTabTitle);
            tab8.setTabListener(this);
            actionBar.addTab(tab8);
            break;
        case 9:
            ActionBar.Tab tab9=actionBar.newTab();
            tab9.setText(addTabTitle);
            tab9.setTabListener(this);
            actionBar.addTab(tab9);
            break;
        case 10:
            ActionBar.Tab tab10=actionBar.newTab();
            tab10.setText(addTabTitle);
            tab10.setTabListener(this);
            actionBar.addTab(tab10);
            break;

        }



    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

First off-  a thread cannot be run twice.  You need to create a new thread object and run it if you want to run 2 in parallel or run it again.

Secondly-  if you do a thread.start immediately followed by a thread.join, the thread is pointless.  I realize this may just have been debug code, but if it isn't you have some architecture problems here.

Comment: Could you provide an example of creating a new thread object since i do want to run it again.

Comment: I added this line of code to the start of the FOR loop. However i do not see any improvements.