# Java IllegalThreadStateException on a basic timer

Tags: java, android

I have code for an android app within android studio to run a method after a 1 second delay:

```
    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loginClicked();
                }
            },
            1000
    );
```

However, it produces this error every time it executes:

> java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: A Looper must be associated with this thread.

I've basically grabbed it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258066/java-run-a-function-after-a-specific-number-of-seconds), so I don't really know what's up.

Comment: Why you're writing java.util.Timer instead of timer and TimerTask too?

Comment: Try without java.util.Timer and import them.

Comment: Then remove loginClicked(); method. If it will work, then the problem is not in timer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579445/illegalthreadstateexception-thread-already-started-occurs-when-using-thread-star

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better to use `Handler` on Android at these situations.

`TimerTask` is pure java and you can see the differences & the other important info in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40339630/4409113

> Some of reported problems with `TimerTask` include:

- Can't update the UI thread
- Memory leaks
- Unreliable (doesn't always work)
- Long running tasks can interfere with the next scheduled event

However, you can use the following codes:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do your things after 1000ms
     loginClicked();
  }
}, 1000);
```